# Why can't my .cpp file have a class of the same name?

Tags: programming, c++, compile

I made a new Arduino IDE `project ABC`, and am given `ABC.ino`. Then I create a `XYZ.h` and `XYZ.cpp`.

---

`ABC.ino`:

```
#include "XYZ.h"

void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

`XYZ.h`:

```
#ifndef XYZ
#define XYZ

#include "Arduino.h"

class XYZ { };

#endif
```

`XYZ.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "XYZ.h"
```

---

When I try to compile this, I get some error:

```
In file included from sketch/XYZ.cpp:2:0:
XYZ:8: error: abstract declarator '<anonymous class>' used as declaration
 };
 ^
exit status 1
abstract declarator '<anonymous class>' used as declaration
```

---

However, when I rename my class to something other than the file name, like `XYZa`, the compilation succeeds.

---

**Why can't I have the same name class as the file?**

I've done C++ projects (independent of Arduino) via `Xcode` and `nano`, and this has never been a problem.

Comment: INCLUDE THE FULL CODE!!!

Comment: @DatHa -- This is the full code. It's extremely boilerplate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define XYZ
...
class XYZ { };
```

After preprocessing, what do you think that ends up as?

Comment: IDK. But, if you're suggesting that it's because it's an empty class, I think I've ruled it out. If you add `void QRS()` to `.h` and `void XYZ::QRS() {}` to `.cpp` I still get that error AND another one.

Comment: Do you know what `#define XYZ` actually does?

Comment: I think it (along with `#ifndef` and `#endif`) is suppose to keep from duplicate code during linking?

Comment: That is what it is being *used* for. I asked if you know what it *does*?

Comment: Not particularly. :)

Comment: Ok. If I tell you that `#define` defines a symbol (`XYZ` in your example) as whatever follows it (nothing at all in your example) then you may see what is happening?

Comment: Ahh!!! Yes. I always assumed `#define` ends at a return carriage. After adjusting the first 2 lines by appending `_H_`, it begins to work. So, that leads to me asking, why does it work now?

Comment: Because now you are defining XYZ_H_ as nothing, and leaving XYZ as XYZ.  When you use #define, any occurrance of the symbol you have defined gets replaced verbatim with what you defined it as (nothing in this case), so by using XYZ  you ended up with XYZ being replaced by nothing, so the class definition ended up as `class  { };`

Answer (score 3):

```
#define XYZ

class XYZ { };
```

The first line tells the "C preprocessor" (called before C and C++ compilers) to replace `XYZ` with nothing everywhere it happens, hence after preprocessing, and before compiling, that code becomes:

```
#define XYZ

class  { };
```

This is where C++ compiler complains. It has nothing to do with your file name.

Among C and C++ programmers, it is commonly admitted that header files should be protected by macros named after the file name **including the extension**:

```
#ifndef XYZ_H
#define XYZ_H
```

If you use this practice, you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: That's what is inconsistent with my Arduino program and my other ones (Xcode/nano). I forgot to append the `_H_` (or `_H` as you prefer).